# What is StringIO() used for in this script?

Tags: python, django, frameworks, stringio

I just started using Django and Python and I'm trying to build a photo app. This script is generating thumbnails and I'd like to do that myself. Unfortunately I don't understand what `StringIO()` is doing. The Python Docs aren't very helpful to me in that case.

Can someone please explain to me what `StringIO()` does in this particular case?

From http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1172/:

```
def save(self):
    from PIL import Image
    #Original photo
    imgFile = Image.open(self.image.path)

    #Convert to RGB
    if imgFile.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
        imgFile = imgFile.convert('RGB')

    #Save a thumbnail for each of the given dimensions
    #The IMAGE_SIZES looks like:
    #IMAGE_SIZES = { 'image_web'      : (300, 348),
    #                'image_large'    : (600, 450),
    #                'image_thumb'    : (200, 200) }
    #each of which corresponds to an ImageField of the same name
    for field_name, size in self.IMAGE_SIZES.iteritems():
        field = getattr(self, field_name)
        working = imgFile.copy()
        working.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        fp = StringIO()
        working.save(fp, "JPEG", quality=95)
        cf = ContentFile(fp.getvalue())
        field.save(name=self.image.name, content=cf, save=False);

    #Save instance of Photo
    super(Photo, self).save()
```

Comment: In the future, please post the code in your question.  StackOverflow makes it easy and readable.

Comment: `StringIO` creates in-memory files (as opposed to normal files created with `open` which usually use the file system), and so you're basically doing file operations in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) is a class which can be used as a file-like object. You can use it exactly as you would a regular file, except instead of the data being written to disk, it will be written to a buffer ( a string buffer ) in memory.

In this script it looks like the image is first saved to a StringIO memory buffer, and after that the value of the string is retrieved and passed to the constructor for ContentFile to create a new instance of ContentFile, which is then passed to the field save function.

I would presume that the reason the script is using StringIO is that the constructor for ContentFile takes in a string, and writting to and then reading a StringIO file is the easiest way to get the image contents represented as a string.

As a side note, I would like to suggest that you look at [Django's ImageFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.images.ImageFile) field type, it has been more than enough for my image related needs, and is more clear than going through StringIO and ContentFiles.

Comment: thanks, i think i got it now :) i'm actually going to use an image field, but while saving the model i want the image to be taken, resized and put into a second image field as a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

StringIO provides the ability to read and write to a string just like one would write to a file.  This could make the coding more convenient, easier, or both.

It also lets you edit strings, unlike regular python strings.

Comment: i got that from the documentation, but why is it used here? i don't get the concept at all. what is actually saved in fp ? the path or the binary file ? why is stringio used here instead of a normal string ?

Comment: @user: The image is saved. However it's not saved to a file, but into the stringIO, i.e. after the call to save the stringIO will contain the contents of the image. The reason that the author didn't use a string is that a) you can't write to a string (strings are read-only), so there's no way the save method could write the contents of the image into a string argument and b) if save gets a string as its first argument, it interprets that as a filename.

Comment: @JasonTS: It's useful as a buffer, where you can do whatever you want to the string, unlike regular python strings.